# Access Nuget Packages hosted in private Nuget Server in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines, msbuildcommunitytasks

We have few nuget packages pushed to Private nuget packages, trying to setup Azure Pipelines however during the build it says error NU1101: Unable to find package while running step "nuget store"

**NOTE** in Local Visual studio it will be accessible when we are in VPN

Answer (score 0):

If you are using private nuget server. You will need to [create self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local machines that have access to the private nuget server. And select your [private agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#default-agent-pools) to run your Azure pipeline on the self hosted agents.

For your private nuget server is unavailable to the cloud hosted agents. If you run your pipeline on the cloud hosted agents, the nuget restore step in your pipeline will fail to find your package.

If you are working behind a proxy. Please check below document to configure the proxy settings for the self-hosted agents.

[Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)